# How to prove that $n! \mid 2^n \prod_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

i would like to prove that

$$
n! \mid 2^n \prod_{i=1}^{n}(2i-1)
$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

HINT: First,

$$(2n)!=\left(\prod_{k=1}^n2k\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)\right)=2^nn!\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)\;.$$

Now combine this with the fact that $\dbinom{2n}n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

You can notice that $$2^n \prod\limits_{i=1}^n (2i-1)= 2^n \prod\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{2i(2i-1)}{2i}= \frac{1}{n!} \prod\limits_{i=1}^n 2i(2i-1)= \frac{(2n)!}{n!}=n!C_{2n}^n$$